# How can I nest materializecss slider within a parallax?

Tags: html, css, slideshow, parallax, materialize

I would like to nest a materializecss slider inside a materialcss parallax. Can this be done?

I can make each work individually fine, but when I nest them I just get a grey area with the captions.

This is my code

```html
<div class="parallax-container">
  
<div class="parallax">
       
    <div class="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
         <li>
           <img src="images/new-york-city.jpg">
           <div class="caption center-align brown-text text-darken-2">
              <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
              <h5 class="light grey-text text-darken-2">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
           </div>
         </li>
         
         <li>
           <img src="images/coffee.jpg">
           <div class="caption center-align blue-grey-text text-darken-4">
              <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
              <h5 class="light blue-grey-text text-darken-4">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
           </div>
         </li>      
        </ul><!-- /slides -->
   </div><!-- /slider -->
      
</div><!-- /parallax -->
</div><!-- /parallax-container -->
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever work out whether this is possible? I'm trying to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use only slider like this:

```html
       
    <div class="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
           <li>
             <img src="images/new-york-city.jpg">
          <div class="caption center-align brown-text text-darken-2">
             <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
             <h5 class="light grey-text text-darken-2">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
          </div>
        </li>
         
        <li>
          <img src="images/coffee.jpg">
          <div class="caption center-align blue-grey-text text-darken-4">
             <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
             <h5 class="light blue-grey-text text-darken-4">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
          </div>
        </li>      
        </ul><!-- /slides -->
   </div><!-- /slider -->
```

then put this in your css file

```
.slides li img {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

it will work fine :)