# How to combine materializecss slider and parallax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I'm trying to combine the media slider and parallax using materializecss framework but I'm unable to make it work, the slide is working but the parallax isn't. Is there a way to fix this without third party js?

Here's the code-pen test markup:
http://codepen.io/mav1283/pen/VKPRKx

```
<nav class="grey darken-3">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="sass.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="badges.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="collapsible.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
<section class="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li class="parallax-container">
                <div class="parallax">
                    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/03/06/05/03/sunrise-1239727_960_720.jpg" alt=""/>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="parallax-container">
                <div class="parallax">
                    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/05/24/11/54/lake-1412216_960_720.jpg" alt=""/>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="parallax-container">
                <div class="parallax">
                    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/01/28/23/34/landscape-615428_960_720.jpg" alt=""/>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <p>    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus pellentesque gravida purus, vitae rutrum lectus imperdiet sed. Integer quis ex quam. Morbi cursus urna sit amet arcu maximus, eget imperdiet leo rutrum. Aliquam molestie mi a ipsum tempor, sed varius sapien molestie. Sed gravida diam in risus porttitor commodo. Aenean lobortis facilisis lacus nec laoreet. Vivamus velit leo, porttitor ac gravida id, elementum ac dolor. Aenean vulputate tellus neque, eget sagittis magna tempus ut. Mauris tortor purus, gravida non orci id, lobortis lacinia lectus. Nunc tempus fringilla augue vestibulum egestas. Aenean iaculis a neque quis interdum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Phasellus scelerisque elementum nisl, a posuere felis faucibus sed.

Donec pulvinar tortor vel arcu consequat, eget hendrerit urna auctor. Praesent fringilla, sapien quis rutrum scelerisque, urna lectus congue nunc, quis sollicitudin est augue at justo. Suspendisse congue justo tellus, fringilla condimentum mauris mattis ac. Praesent a efficitur turpis. Pellentesque et eros purus. Phasellus sit amet est mauris. Sed bibendum blandit porta. Aenean sed efficitur ligula. Nulla interdum tincidunt sapien vel sagittis. Mauris nisl tortor, rutrum quis volutpat sed, egestas et magna. Praesent scelerisque laoreet tortor gravida viverra. Vestibulum facilisis placerat purus at venenatis. Donec et est pellentesque, tempus risus et, ullamcorper lectus. Donec ut tortor tellus. Vivamus vitae diam a libero rutrum eleifend sed sed turpis. In fermentum lacus eget neque lacinia rutrum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Did you ever work out a way to do this? I'm trying to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is a documented issue on github, and it's still open. Check [issue#5271](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5271) for more detail.

Here is some possible solutions form that:

**1. it works when combined with carousel tho.**

```
<section class="car-hero-cont section no-pad" data-section-name="home">
    <div class="car-hero parallax-container carousel carousel-slider center">
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="car-hero-content">
                <p>One Of Dubai's Most Trusted Brokers</p>
                <a href="{{ url('abusssss')}}" class="btn-flat white-text waves-effect waves-light">Property List</a>
                <a href="{{ url('abusssss')}}" class="btn-flat white-text waves-effect waves-light">Property for Sale</a>
                <a href="{{ url('abusssss')}}" class="btn-flat white-text waves-effect waves-light">Property for Rent</a>
            </div>
            <div class="parallax"><img src="{{asset('images/banner3-2.jpg')}}" ></div>
        </div>
</div>
</section>
```

**2. slides code + one css line of code -not using parallax class at all.**
It's an answer on SO that is similar to yours.
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459124/how-can-i-nest-materializecss-slider-within-a-parallax/46580003#46580003)